# How to calculate Hugin lens data for Aerial Photos

Tags: metadata, hugin, aerial-photography

I have some aerial photographs from the 60s and 70s I want to stitch together. I known nothing about the camera that took these photos, and am not sure how to calculate the Focal Length or Horizontal Field of View (HFOV). Are any values perhaps a better guess?

I have never used this program or anything like it before. The pictures were taken in a straight line, probably by an airplane.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have overlapping areas and can set control points, it should work nevertheless.  The resulting FOV may be incorrect (it is ill-defined in Hugin anyway) but this does not mean a bad output. The resulting FOV is accurate only if you have a 360° panorama.

Comment: Is there any way to have the program automatically find control points if I specify a random HFOV?

Comment: It should do that--just use a reasonable guesstimate. It's worked for me with Hugin and PTGui. As long as you have enough overlap, it should work.